# Remove duplicate rows only if the page column is not the same

Tags: python-3.x, drop-duplicates

I am super new to python. i am able to remove duplicate rows, but I need to only remove rows if they are from different pages.

this is my dataframe

| name | ntgs | phi | sw | per | page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bav2 | 0.59 | 0.3 | 0.15 | 1000 | 1 |
| bav2 | 0.59 | 0.3 | 0.15 | 1000 | 3 |
| clo_1 | 0.78 | 0.308 | 0.155 | 1509 | 2 |
| clo_1 | 0.78 | 0.308 | 0.155 | 1509 | 2 |
| clo_1 | 0.78 | 0.308 | 0.155 | 1509 | 2 |

this is the result I want

| name | ntgs | phi | sw | per | page |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bav2 | 0.59 | 0.3 | 0.15 | 1000 | 1 |
| clo_1 | 0.78 | 0.308 | 0.155 | 1509 | 2 |
| clo_1 | 0.78 | 0.308 | 0.155 | 1509 | 2 |
| clo_1 | 0.78 | 0.308 | 0.155 | 1509 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [`subset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html)

`df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name','page'], keep=False)`